# Are humming birds more like planes or helicopters?

Tags: birds

Hummingbirds fly, helicopters fly, planes fly. They all have tails, however, planes generate lift with thrust and wing shape, helicopters generate lift via their spinning blades birds use both similar principles to planes and helicopters. Hummingbirds flap their wings generating lift and thrust like a helicopter and they can stay in place like one, and they glide easily. Their wing shape also helps them in flight. So, what is closer?

Comment: Welcome, but I don't think this question is a good fit here.  For one, birds are really nothing like either, so there is no real answer to the question.  All you will get is opinions and chat.

Comment: By a flight characteristics point of view I'd say a helicopter (an airplane cannot hover). By an aerodynamic point of view I'd say a [cyclogyro](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclogyro).

Answer (score 3):

A hummingbird wing is more like an *insect wing* than either of your examples because it exhibits very large torsional flexure while being flapped and it generates lift on both strokes (forward and aft).

Comment: +1 This is the best answer I've ever seen that doesn't answer the OP's exact question.